# jQuery .contentWindow.document.getElementById('email_box').value help

Tags: jquery

Hey all, i'm just wondering if there was any way to condense this line of code to pure jQuery without having the need to have ".contentWindow.document.getElementById('email_box').value" in there?

```
 $('#OIPHPFrame')[0].contentWindow.document.getElementById('email_box').value = $("#txtEmail").val();
```

and also the "click" event:

```
 $('#OIPHPFrame')[0].contentWindow.document.getElementById('butImport').click();
```

Any help would be awesome! :o)

**SOLVED! :o)**

```
 $('#OIPHPFrame').contents().find('#password_box').val($("#Password").val());
 $('#OIPHPFrame').contents().find('#butImport').click();
```

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think...

```
$('#OIPHPFrame')[0].find('#email_box').val();
$('#OIPHPFrame')[0].find('#butImport').click();
```

...should work.

Comment: sadly it says "Error: $("#OIPHPFrame")[0].find is not a function"

Comment: Glad I could help!  Frames are, unfortunately, a necessary evil still.